# PHP json string variable

Tags: php, json, string

I want to decode a JSON string. However, the value that I got is something like this `string(100) "{"data":{"type":"campaign-folders","id":"d208f3171a","attributes":{"name":"My Folder"}}}"`.

Could anyone tell me what should I do so that I can treat this variable as a usual string ?

Comment: _“However, the value that I got is something like this”_ - that looks like the output var_dump creates - but in that case, it of course does not mean that this is the actual content of your string variable. `string(100)` is additional “meta data” var_dump provides you with (type & length.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_decode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work. I think I should treat the string differently, but it's just the same

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode ,you can solve it.

```
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));//check this.
```

Answer (score 0):

here to convert JSON string to Array

```
 $someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
  print_r($someArray);
 echo $someArray[0]["name"];
```

and here to convert JSON to Object

```
$someObject = json_decode($someJSON);
 print_r($someObject);
 echo $someObject[0]->name;
```